How to make a POST request using HttpClient with a PFX certificate
I'm using the latest .NET 8's HttpClient to call an API endpoint.
This is my code:
var cert = new X509Certificate("myCert.pfx", "mypass");

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
};

handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

using var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://<my-url>");

var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

It generated the following exception:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

This seems to suggest that the private key is not working as expected. I used the same certificate file and password on Postman and the request succeeded and returned meaningful results.
Here are some of the things I have tried:

Double-checked my password
Breaking up the pfx file into a certificate and private key
Specify the request as TLS 1.2

None of the above worked.

Do you install the root certificate?

Use X509Certificate2 instead of X509Certificate.

HttpClientHandler is only for .NET Framework and .NET Core 1 + 2, and not .NET 8 - you should be using SocketsHttpHandler (yes, this is confusing and inconsistently documented).

Your code is mixing types meant for .NET Framework (4.x) and older versions of .NET Core; ostensibly code using them should work without modification on .NET 8 but the program won't run as well as it could - though in practice I find that's going to cause errors like "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.".

X509Certificate2 should be used instead of X509Certificate (which dates back to .NET Framework 1.x in 2002; whereas X509Certificate2 supplanted it and was added in .NET Framework 2.0 in 2005).

HttpClientHandler is only for .NET Framework and .NET Core 1 + 2, and not .NET 8 - you should be using SocketsHttpHandler. (yes, this is confusing and inconsistently documented).

Though HttpClientHandler is still available in .NET 8, internally it's just a wrapper over SocketsHttpHandler.


I note that your reported error 0x80090326 is indicative of an inability of both-ends to agree on cipher-suite algo).


I suggest that you change your code to this and give it a spin:
X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(
    fileName: "myCert.pfx",
    password: "mypass"
);

if( !clientCert.HasPrivateKey ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Private key not loaded." );

SocketsHttpHandler socksHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    SslOptions =
    {
//      CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy( ... ) // Only uncomment this if the underlying TLS error is due to a client/server disagreement over what TLS algos to use and this is the *only* way to resolve it.
        ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection()
        {
            clientCert
        },
//      SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 // Only uncomment this if you actually really need to specify exactly TLS 1.2. By default it will be negotiated.
    }
};

using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient( socksHandler );

using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync( "https://<my-url>", etc );

String responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

